# How to do test automation for event driven architecture

Tags: spring-boot, testing, apache-kafka, event-driven

We have a service A, which has AWS MSK event listener. It then processes the event and adds data into db.
We have get API on the service, which provides the data referring to the db in step above.

We have implemented integration tests with embedded kafka and SpringBoot test. However for QA automation testing, we are figuring out how to write automated tests for invoking kafka event for end to end test.
Any ideas or pointers would be helpful.

Comment: EmbeddedKafka or Testcontainers are commonly used. What's wrong with that? Also, Kafka Connect is recommended for working with databases

Comment: EmbeddedKafka is the way to test locally for developers. That we are already doing. What we want is automation for QE which would test with real systems.

Comment: Testcontainers, or vagrant, then. Otherwise, introduce terraform/ansible and spin up a test environment in MSK, assuming you're willing to pay for every test that gets ran.

Comment: I am not able to find any example of testcontainer with real kafka. Mostly use embedded kafka which is not going to serve my purpose.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "real". The container runs just a real broker as anything else. You don't link the test container to an external system